# NestJS HTTP Module needs to be imported in every feature module

Tags: api, rest, nestjs

In nestjs the http module needs to be imported into every feature module. Is there any way to import the http module only once throughout the full application?

Although in all the feature modules the http configurations are the same, why do we need to import and configure in each one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could make a global module that imports it and exports it like so:

```js
@Global()
@Module({
  imports: [HttpModule.register(httpModuleOptions)],
  exports: [HttpModule],
})
export class GlobalHttpModule {}
```

Now import it in the `AppModule` and you can use `HttpService` anywhere

Comment: Thanks mate. Can you also put a reference to where I can read more about this? Noob at nestjs here.

Comment: @RohitGupta [module re-exporting](https://docs.nestjs.com/modules#module-re-exporting) and [global modules](https://docs.nestjs.com/modules#global-modules)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to create a wrapper module, you can also:

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    {
      ...HttpModule.register(httpModuleOptions),
      global: true
    }
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```